Linking to ARPACK-NG
I am in Ubuntu 22.04, using rust and I am trying to link against arpack using a wrapping library.
Currently I am running into this linking error:
/home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/algebra/target/debug/deps/algebra-ba0010f409bd2787: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
error: test failed, to rerun pass `--lib`

Some searching suggests that this is due to the version of lapack I have installed, I have tried multiple without luck:
apt list --installed | grep .*lapa.*

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

liblapack-dev/jammy,now 3.10.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
liblapack3/jammy,now 3.10.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
liblapacke-dev/jammy,now 3.10.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
liblapacke/jammy,now 3.10.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

I am not sure what to do from here.
The issue seems to be that the arpack-ng-sys crate and the lapack crate are linking against different versions of lapack. If I use only one of the two then the binary does link properly. But if I add both to the toml file then I get the linker error.
update-alternatives --query liblapack.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
Name: liblapack.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
Link: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so
Slaves:
 lapack.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/lapack.pc
 liblapack.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.a
Status: auto
Best: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so
Value: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so

Alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so
Priority: 35
Slaves:
 lapack.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/lapack-atlas.pc
 liblapack.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.a

Alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so
Priority: 10
Slaves:
 lapack.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/lapack-netlib.pc
 liblapack.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.a

Alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so
Priority: 100
Slaves:
 lapack.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/pkgconfig/lapack-openblas.pc
 liblapack.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.a

 update-alternatives --query libblas.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
Name: libblas.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
Link: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so
Slaves:
 blas.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/blas.pc
 cblas.h-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas.h
 libblas.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.a
Status: auto
Best: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so
Value: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so

Alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so
Priority: 35
Slaves:
 blas.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/blas-atlas.pc
 cblas.h-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas-atlas.h
 libblas.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.a

Alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so
Priority: 100
Slaves:
 blas.pc-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/pkgconfig/blas-openblas.pc
 cblas.h-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/cblas.h
 libblas.a-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.a

realpath /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3


The first thing to do in any question is to include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Yes it does matter. Please edit the question and add this info.

@DavidDE edited

I suspect this may be because you have installed the netlib version of BLAS (package libblas-dev) instead of the OpenBLAS implementation (package libopenblas-dev). For background (in particular, the origin of the goto symbol prefix), see What is the relation between BLAS, LAPACK and ATLAS

@steeldriver I tried uninstalling every blas package on my system and then install only libopenblas-dev. I get the same linker error.

Hmm so maybe the issue is there is simply a mismatch between the implementations of the lapack and blas libs? Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of update-alternatives --query liblapack.so-x86_64-linux-gnu, update-alternatives --query libblas.so-x86_64-linux-gnu and realpath /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3

@steeldriver added additional information

Thanks - I don't see anything wrong there - tbh I don't think there's anything more I can suggest without a better understanding of what you're trying to build / steps to reproduce the issue (or at least, the actual linker command that is throwing the error)

@steeldriver It seems that it is a conflict between the way that the lapack crate and the arpack-ng-sys crates are handling linking. So more of a rust issue than ubuntu it seems.
